# Interviewed for a job I wanted. Didn't get it, now it's being readvertised

Tags: interviewing

Earlier this year I applied for a job with a local company after they posted ads on a hiring site. I feel like this is an interesting company and I would have really liked to take a position there. The role was for an experienced programmer.

I ended up getting an interview and felt like it went really well. I was technically qualified and had experience in their specialisation. Unfortunately after another round of interviews I was informed that the position went to another candidate.

So far no problem, but now about a month later I notice that there are a couple of new postings for the same or similar roles. I'd really like to be considered but I'm not sure if I should reapply. What should I do?

I've thought of:

- Applying directly and see what happens
- Calling personally and asking if there's any further feedback I could be given on my interview
- Just not applying since they already know who I am

I'm not sure exactly why I wasn't offered the role in the first place, but there were several interview questions about expected salary. Perhaps they were not even willing to make an offer.

Comment: You can't know for sure that you were deemed entirely unsuitable for the job.  It might be being re-advertised because they filled it but the person they offered it to changed their mind.  You might have been their second choice for all you know.  No harm in applying again.  The worst than can happen is that you don't get the job again.

Comment: If you think you asked for more money than they wanted to pay, they might have gone with someone cheaper and found out it didn’t work.

Answer (score 3):

Apply again with your updated resume.  Companies go through change and turnover.  Whomever got the position may have had to move, or may have gotten promoted, or any number of other things.

If you want the job, pursue it.  That you keep showing interest in the company may be a plus in this round of interviews.

Just not applying shows that you don't want the job.  They may "know who you are" but it is important to show initiative and interest.

"Hey, I saw the position is open.  I am interested."  That shows interest, and that you've kept them in mind.